# I want to import CSV with strapi v4. But I can’t

Tags: strapi

I used this package when I was strapi V3.
CSV was imported.

https://github.com/EdisonPeM/strapi-plugin-import-export-content

However, this package is not compatible with v4 and cannot be used.
Therefore, I would like to know how to import CSV in V4.

#### System Information

1. Strapi Version:4.1.5
2. Operating System: m1 mac monterey 12.1
3. Database: postgres
4. Node Version16.18.1:
5. NPM Version: 8.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the last update of Strapi plugin to import and export to csv or json has been done 5 days ago go check:
https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-import-export-entries#install-now-section

Comment: Does this work with CSV files? or is it just for JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below plugin for importing/exporting csv and json.

https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-import-export-entries

Edit: Above url is not working try below url.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-import-export-entries

Comment: page gives error

Comment: @AlpAltunel Try the npm link shared above.

Answer (score -1):

Been waiting for this fix to be published too for a while. I think the answer is in migrating plugin from v3 format

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Request you to make the answer clearer so that other members of the community can gain from this.